# Como fazer funcionar um campo de resgate de Email - Newsletter

Tags: html, formulário

No rodapé de todas as páginas do site que estou mexendo tem um campo de Subscribe, para resgate de email e envio de newsletter.
Porém não sei fazer ele funcionar, alguém me ajuda?

Segue:

```
 <form class="newsletter">
    <input type="email" name="EMAIL" placeholder="Seu endereço de e-mail" required />
    <button><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
 </form>
```

Comment: Pode postar alguma amostra do código?

Comment: Defina "funcionar".

Comment: Seu formulário precisa de um atributo `action` apontando para o servidor que vai receber os dados.

Comment: Então sua dúvida é na parte do PHP?

Comment: @bfavaretto Não sei se é o php ou se tenho que usar algum script pra isso... eu não sei mexer em javascript. 
No formulário, quando clico em enviar sou direcionada para a página do php. 
mesmo eu utilizando o Location: index.html .

Comment: No PHP vc verifica se no form foi enviado um email válido, aí vc cadastra no banco.